# how java GUI application receive parameter?

Tags: exe4j

I have a Java program that has both console and GUI mode.If started without parameters (double click it) it comes up as a GUI program.If at least one argument (by cmd) is passed in, it comes up as command line.

Now, I need to convert it to .exe application on windows. I used exe4j, and I did selected "Allow-console parameter", next next next. Successful generated .exe.

Doubue click the .exe file, it can be launched as a GUI program; but when I started it through cmd like this: >test.exe param1 prama1

Nothing happens, no system.out showed, i don't know what to do? it takes me so much time on it.  How should I do?

Comment: You tried test.exe -param1 -prama1 ?

Comment: yes i tried, and nothing happens